# How to resolve W/NetworkRequest: errors while trying to download image from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm currently creating an android project (A Vehicle Rental System) with Firebase as a server. Realtime Database is alright, meanwhile, every time I try to access the images stored in the Firebase Storage, it always gives out an error:

```
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest: No App Check token for request.
W/NetworkRequest: error sending network request GET /*insert imageURI here*/ failed
W/ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.
```

Here is my CustomAdapter:

```
    private ArrayList<ModelItem> modelItemsArrayList;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    private static final String TAG = "ModelAdapter: ";

    private FirebaseStorage storage;
    private StorageReference storageReference;

    private Context context;

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        onItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    public static class ModelAdapterViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView modelImageView;
        public TextView modelTextView;
        public TextView brandTextView;
        public CardView modelCardView;

        public ModelAdapterViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            modelImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvFrontProfileImageView);
            modelTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvModelTextView);
            brandTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvBrandTextView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                if(listener != null) {
                    int position = getBindingAdapterPosition();
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        listener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public ModelAdapter(ArrayList<ModelItem> modelItemsArrayList) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ModelAdapter: called");
        this.modelItemsArrayList = modelItemsArrayList;
        Log.d(TAG, "ModelAdapter: modelItemsArrayList.size() = " + modelItemsArrayList.size());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ModelAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model_item_cardview, parent, false);

        return new ModelAdapterViewHolder(view, onItemClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ModelAdapter.ModelAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //enter data from Firebase here
        ModelItem currentItem = modelItemsArrayList.get(position);
        Log.d(TAG, "modelItemsArraylist.size() = " + modelItemsArrayList.size());

        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://roadtrip-7a905.appspot.com/")
                .child(currentItem.getmImageResource());

        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: inside try catch nest");
            final File file = File.createTempFile("image", "jpg");
            storageReference.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    holder.modelImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + file.getPath() + " successfully loaded");
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Load image: " + currentItem.getmImageResource(),
                        //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: addOnFailureListener: " + e.toString());
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + e.toString());
        }

        //holder.modelImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getmImageResource()); ==> setFile from storage here
        holder.modelTextView.setText(currentItem.getmModelText());
        holder.brandTextView.setText(currentItem.getmBrandText());

        Log.d(TAG, currentItem.getmImageResource() + "\n"
                + currentItem.getmModelText() + "\n"
                + currentItem.getmBrandText());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelItemsArrayList.size();
    }
```

And here is my CustomClass

```
package com.example.roadtrip;

public class ModelItem {
    private String mImageResource;
    private String mModelText;
    private String mBrandText;

    public ModelItem() {
    }

    public ModelItem(String mImageResource, String mModelText, String mBrandText) {
        this.mImageResource = mImageResource;
        this.mModelText = mModelText;
        this.mBrandText = mBrandText;
    }

    public String getmImageResource() {
        return mImageResource;
    }

    public void setmImageResource(String mImageResource) {
        this.mImageResource = mImageResource;
    }

    public String getmModelText() {
        return mModelText;
    }

    public void setmModelText(String mModelText) {
        this.mModelText = mModelText;
    }

    public String getmBrandText() {
        return mBrandText;
    }

    public void setmBrandText(String mBrandText) {
        this.mBrandText = mBrandText;
    }
}
```

I've been stuck for more than a week already. Can someone help me?

P.S. It's my first time posting here. I apologize for the Logs in the code, I was just trying to debug.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Oh, got it. Will edit shortly.